# Jmeter error 404

Tags: http-headers, jmeter, fiddler

I am trying to load test a webapp, which has following functonality
 1. Login in app (setting some cookie variables ) 
 2. Serach customer with some parameter 
 3. Get detail of particular customer
 4. Logout from webapp
When i am running Jmeter i am getting status code 404 
Any reference or help will be appriciated.

After googling i found 4** says you have sent bad request. 
To check what request has been sent i am using fiddler and capturing original request (which is working from browser ) and request sent by Jmeter , I am comparing data under *Inspector* tab in *Headers* in fiddler, Is this right way to resolve the issue of 4**. What  else i can do to fix this issue ?

Screen shots attached 
[image: Proxy Configuration][image: SuccessfullLogin][image: After login faliure]

Comment: Http Cookie manager is the way to go, do you receive the 404 even for the login page?

Comment: @Carlo  No i am not getting 4** code for login page, i am able to login successfully

Comment: can you give a screenshot or explain when exactly do you get this error? what steps are successful and when this starts to happen, we can't see your screen

Comment: @ant i have attached screen shot let me know if you want any other information

Comment: What kind of authentication does the app use? Query parameters or windows NTLM authentication?
And it would be easier to answer if you can attach screenshots of the requests you are sending in both the cases. (Success as well as failure)

Comment: Verify if your requests need to "Follow Redirects" as some of them would return 302 and this will cause the request to be sent twice: one from redirection and another from captured request in JMeter Test Plan. If possible, add an image of the Request tab of the fourth and fifth sampler.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the HTTP header manager and HTTP cookie manager must be pushed up just before Recording Controller. Otherwise the requests are made without these header or cookie informations.

If you doing localhost testing should in the cookie manager config domain
localhost:8080.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the request/response in View Results Tree. Just click on the tab Request or Response data respectively. If you're getting a 404, chances are the Response data tab will contain the 404 with (hopefully) information about the values that are invalid or missing.