# how to get pass in Jmeter reports for 404 response codes?

Tags: jmeter, httpresponse, jmeter-plugins, web-api-testing

Scenario:

I am doing API testing using Jmeter. I have added a response code assertion there for 404 i.e. I  am expecting 404.

So when I am expecting it, it should be green but it is red (it appears green for 200). How can I fix it?

I am using `Jmeter 3.x on windows` and listener is `JMeter View Results in table`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305541/jmeter-error-404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override sampler result, using JSR223 Assertion (or any other programmable assertion or post-processor):

1. Add JSR223 Assertion under the sampler you want to pass when response code is 404:

[image]

2. Set assertion so that it passes if response code is 404, and in that case also modify sampler's result to be successful. In all other cases, set assertion to fail, and do not modify sampler status:

   ```
   if("404".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode())) { // Success
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(true); // Change sampler status to success
       AssertionResult.setFailure(false); // Set assertion status to success as well
   } 
   else {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true); // Set assertion status to failure
   }
   ```

This code only overrides the status, you may however change any other fields of the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) and [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html)

Example:

When response code is 404, sampler and assertion will succeed:

[image]

When response code is 200, sampler will initially succeed, but will fail due to assertion:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

In the below image, first request is 404 and the response assertion is 404. So, the HTTP sampler failed as it is 404 but the assertion passed as you can see there is no expand sign in the first HTTP sampler.

In the second sampler, it is giving 200 but the response assertion is 404. Hence, the HTTP sampler is failed due to assertion.

Assertion will fail the HTTP sampler if not found, but cannot make it green if it is 404 response without any extra settings.

[image]

Now, solution for this, you can use "Ignore Status" checkbox to pass the sampler even it is 404 and assertion is also 404 as shown below:-

[image]

[image]